# Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I started to Bootstrap a new `Spring Boot project with JSP` and I get the following errors in the console,

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@515f550a
;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@515f550a


2017-09-25 10:23:51.958  WARN 1520 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.a.orm.jpa.DatabaseLookup           : Unable to determine jdbc url from datasource

org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Could not get Connection for extracting meta data; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver from ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@515f550a
;ClassLoader:ParallelWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: false
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@515f550a
```

The project structure is provided,

[image]

It started when I have added new entity `User` and the code is provided below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    private Long id;

    private String username;

    private String password;

    private String passwordConfirm;

//    private Set<Role> roles;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Transient
    public String getPasswordConfirm() {
        return passwordConfirm;
    }

    public void setPasswordConfirm(String passwordConfirm) {
        this.passwordConfirm = passwordConfirm;
    }

//    @ManyToMany
//    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
//    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
//        return roles;
//    }

//    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
//        this.roles = roles;
//    }
}
```

The code for the `WebApplication` is provided below,

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(WebApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(WebApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Finally, the `pom.xml` file is provided,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>hello-springboot</artifactId>
    <name>hello-springboot</name>
    <description>hello-springboot</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I plan to use `HSQL` database for the project. The `application.properties` file provided below,

```
server.port=8081
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.application.name=Bootstrap Spring Boot
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true 
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths=.
#security.basic.enabled=true
#security.user.name=john
#security.user.password=123
#spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:bootapp;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=testuser
spring.datasource.password=testpassword
server.error.path=/error
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false 
# Set here configurations for the database connection
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Registration
# Username and secret
# Keep the connection alive if idle for a long time (needed in production)
spring.datasource.testWhileIdle=true
spring.datasource.validationQuery=SELECT 1
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
# Use spring.jpa.properties.* for Hibernate native properties (the prefix is
# stripped before adding them to the entity manager).
# Show or not log for each sql query
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, update): with "update" the database
# schema will be automatically updated accordingly to java entities found in
# the project

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
# Allows Hibernate to generate SQL optimized for a particular DBMS
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
#spring.mail.host=smtp.gmail.com
#spring.mail.username=ray.deng83@gmail.com
#spring.mail.password=Rochester25
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.port=465
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.class=javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory
#spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback=false
#support.email=ray.deng83@gmail.com
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Could you post your database configuration

Comment: Your `pom.xml` has a dependency on HSQL but your error message and tags say MySQL. Make up your mind.

Comment: OK. I get it. Most of the previous projects I have worked with `MySQL` but in this test project, I plan to use the `HSQL`. After changing the `application.`properties` file, the error is solved.

Comment: any luck finding the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had this weird looking error recently.
I know it passed 3 years but writing this for the community.

If you are facing this error, head to the catalina.out (if you are deploying it).
Usually the error `"ParallelWebappClassLoader"` is not your problem and you should look at the end of this exception to find the thing `caused by xxxx` there you will see mentions of some other detailed error, my case was to add the json dependency yours is probably adding the jdbc dependency of your choice(as it is Mysql) and add the scope compile to it.

Good luck.